# How to use special characters in url helper without encoding?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to show a table of centers. With each center I want to provide an edit button which use data from angular:

```
       <table data-ng-init="centers" data-ng-model="Centers">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="center in centers">
            <td class="center-logo">
            </td>
            <td class="center-name">
                <h4>{{center.Name}}</h4>
            </td>
            <td class="center-address">{{center.City}}, {{center.Country}}
            </td>
            <td>{{center.StudyVersion}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Center",new {code = {{center.Code}}})" class="btn">
                    <i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now VS is giving me an error on the expression:

```
@Url.Action("Edit","Center",new {code = "{{center.Code}}"})
```

I can't seem to find a way so razor is using the value from {{center.Code} like it does in plain html.

Comment: Could you please post the error you are getting from Studio?

Comment: At {{center.Code} it says expression expected.

Comment: Your statement: _"can't seem to find a way so razor is using the value from {{center.Code} like it does in plain html."_ is a little bit confusing.  Razor is server-side, but I believe the double curly-braces as you're using them, and the contained value `center.code` are meaningful only to AngularJS which is client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
`@Html.Raw()` from initial answer isn't required.  Sorry I spoke too soon.  Answer edited to reflect this.

The following works for me:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Edit","Center")/code={{center.Code}}' class="btn">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit
</a>
```

Hope that helps.